# If tick box ticked force completion of text area

Tags: php, forms

I have created a php form on the form there is a field called "alert" and I wan to set the form so that if the "alert" tick box is ticked them the user must enter a comment why they ticked the alert box.

Here is the code I have

```
if (empty($_POST['tutorComment']) && $_POST['alert'] == 'YES') {
    echo "You must enter a comment on the student if you tick the alert box";
    exit();
}
```

This seems to work if I tick the box and don't enter a comment but when I tick the box and enter a comment the code still terminates here.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Is your issue the if-clause or something else?

Comment: I'm not sure, try using ` if(!isset($_POST['tutorcomments'))`

Comment: try var_dump($_POST) and you'll see all your post-parameters.

Comment: What comment did you enter? `"0"` is "empty" in PHP.

Comment: Did you validate the output of your post the print_r($_POST) for verification? It helps to analyze

Comment: Added the var dump and got these results
array
  'studentName' => string 'Sabana Patel' (length=12)
  'tutorName' => string 'Matt Test User' (length=14)
  'procedure' => string 'sdd' (length=3)
  'grade' => string 'N' (length=1)
  'studentReflection' => string 'ddd' (length=3)
  'professionalism' => string 'U' (length=1)
  'communication' => string 'U' (length=1)
  'alert' => string 'YES' (length=3)
  'tutorComments' => string 'fdffffffff' (length=10)

Comment: @Mattrsa: "tutorComments" is not the same as "tutorComment", buddy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your code, it's `tutorComments` and not `tutorComment`. Anyway it would be safer if you replaced your code with:

```
if( !strlen($_POST['tutorComment']) && isset($_POST['alert']) ){
    echo "You must enter a comment on the student if you tick the alert box";
    exit();
}
```

Comment: your right!this just goes to show you can look at code too long and it becomes a blur and you can't spot the simplest things. Thanks very much for the help.

Comment: @mattrsa you're welcome! P.S. if the answer is correct, you should accept it to keep people from trying to answer it :)

Answer (score 2):

Is `tutorComment` the `name` of your form field?  I'd double check spelling, case, and that you've used it as the `name`, not the `id`.

Comment: yes tutorComment is correct, the field will pass information into my database fine if I remove the if statement.

Comment: You were right, it was a spelling issue. I have spent too long staring at the screen

Comment: @Mattrsa: No, it's not correct.  The output you showed us reads "tutorComments", not "tutorComment". Silly bug.